# 画像のRGB値について、縦方向に平均値を計算し、その値を使って横に細長い画像を作りたい

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

縦aピクセル、横bピクセルの画像に対して、縦方向のRGB値についてそれぞれ平均値をとり、その平均値を使って、縦1ピクセル、横bピクセルの画像を作成したいのですが、3次元配列にうまく変換できません。どうすればよいでしょうか。

```
 import cv2
 import numpy as np

 img =cv2.imread ('input.jpg')
 b_mean = img[:,:,0].mean(axis=0)
 g_mean = img[:,:,1].mean(axis=0)
 r_mean = img[:,:,2].mean(axis=0)
 img_mean = np.stack([b_mean, g_mean, r_mean], 1)
 img_mean = img_mean.astype(np.uint8)
 cv2.imwrite('output.jpg', img_mean)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
#img_mean = np.stack([b_mean, g_mean, r_mean], 1)
img_mean = np.stack([b_mean, g_mean, r_mean], 1)[None,:,:]
```